# My laptop monitor shows a white and gray blend

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display, dell-inspiron

I have to adjust the angle of the laptop screen, sometimes I have to completely close it and open. Here's a picture of how the screen looks like:

[image: picture]

Can anyone tell me how to fix this before it gets any worse? This thing cost me a lot.

It's a Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Gaming.

Comment: Have you tried connecting it to a second monitor? If it displays normally, then your monitor has a problem. If not, then your display/graphics adapter has a problem.

Comment: @iTechieGamer My laptop only supports HDMI, I only have a VGA external monitor (and plus, I have no HDMI cable anyway)

Comment: It seems that you have another device. You can use a third-party software to make it as a second monitor.

Comment: @iTechieGamer Already figured that something's wrong with my laptop's display. It wasn't like this before. I just want to know whether this is some electrostatic problem or anything complicated like that. If it was a software problem, I would have fixed it by now.

Comment: there are HDMI to VGA Converters available, so you could buy such a device to test it. later use the adapter to have 2 monitors to work with.

Comment: any update? Do you see a picture with a HDMI to VGA converter and your 2nd Monitor?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I couldn't buy the HDMI to VGA converters, since I'm just a kid. But what I DO know is that this is a hardware problem. I have to bend the monitor (which is a bit flexible) to properly display the things. But it keeps getting worse and worse, and I need to bend it even more to display what's on the screen. Eventually the monitor will break, and I have to use an HDMI to VGA converter - or even replace my laptop (I'm still in my warranty)

Comment: if you're still on warranty contact the support of the laptop manufacture and send it to repair.